# Foundation navigation

Tags: zurb-foundation, nav

I'm having problems with Zurb's foundation navigation (I'm new to this and I'm having a steep learning curve and I've hit a wall)

I would like to do a couple of things:

1. Have the "menu icon" on the left hand side when the topbar is being toggled.
2. I would like to have three sections when the topbar is being toggled (Title/Middle/Menu)

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<nav class="top-bar">
<ul class="title-area">
<!-- Title Area -->
<li class="name"><a href="index.html"></a><h1>Title</h1></li>
<li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>MENU</span></a></li>
</ul>
    <section class="top-bar-section"> 

<!-- Right Nav Section -->
    <ul class="right">
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li class="has-dropdown"> <a href="#"></a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
            <li class="divider"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="divider"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="divider"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li class="divider"><a href="#"></a></li>



    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code :

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
  <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name">
      <h1><a href="#">My Site</a></h1>
    </li>
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
  </ul>

  <section class="top-bar-section">
    <!-- Right Nav Section -->
    <ul class="right">
      <li class="has-dropdown">
        <a href="#">Menu</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">First link in dropdown</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Second link in dropdown</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</nav>
```

Go on : http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html#